# Eventos MySQL entre 12 horas

Tags: mysql, sql, sybase

estoy creando un evento que ya estaba creado en Sybase, este está hecho de manera que se ejecuta cada hora pero lo hace entre 7 de la mañana y 7 de la tarde. ¿Alguien sabe si esta opción está disponible con MySQL? he estado mirando pero no veo nada referente a esta opción.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL tiene un [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) que te permitiría emular lo que describes. Ignoro la granularidad con que puedes definir eventos en Sybase, pero a medida que lo vayas tuneando podrías logras más o menos lo mismo.

La [creación de un evento](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) tiene la sintaxis:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO
  UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

Ahora, tú quieres un evento que ocurra cada 10 minutos, pero sólo entre dos horas específicas. Una manera podría ser:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE EVENT my_event ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 MINUTE DO
IF CURRENT_TIME BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '19:00:00' THEN
   UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
END IF//

DELIMITER ;
```

También podrías jugar con las cláusulas START y ENDS, pero tendrías que ir probando, porque la cláusula ENDS podría interpretarse como que cumplido ese plazo el evento deja de ejecutarse.

Tienes que revisar que el scheduler esté habilitado en tu instalación de MySQL. Si pones

```
 SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

quedará habilitado, pero si en la configuración inicial está deshabilitado, se perderá ese setting cuando reinicies el servicio. Tienes que asegurarte que en tu archivo de configuración aparezca `event_scheduler=ON` para que esté habilitado siempre.

En servicios donde no tienes acceso a la configuración del servicio, como Amazon RDS, tienes que jugar con los parámetros de la instancia, [como describen aquí](https://techtavern.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/mysql-scheduled-events-and-amazon-rds/).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, por más que busqué y probé no se me ocurrió lo del if.

Comment: @OscarMarésBarrera si esta respuesta ha solucionado tu problema, recuerda **[aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)**